# Soap request failing. Server or code issue?

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to setup a data request for a site, but, am running into a problem when trying to pull the data.

I tested the url and credentials using http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html and it works perfectly so I know the service is up and the correct credentials are being entered, but, when using the code below, I'm given the following error;

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Invalid Login] in...

The full code (except generalized URL) that I'm using to make the request is;

```
<?php
$client2 = new SoapClient("http://www.example.com/api/soap.php?wsdl", array('trace'=> true));
$results2 = $client2->boxInfo(array(
                                  "customer" => 'XBLK', 
                                   "size"  => "four",
                                   "price" => "twenty"));
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($client2-> __getLastRequestHeaders());
var_dump($client2-> __getLastRequest());
var_dump($client2-> __getLastResponseHeaders());
var_dump($client2-> __getLastResponse());
var_dump($results2);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

As I'm new to these calls, I'm not sure if I missed something with the SOAP installation when I updated php (I verified it's installed and enabled) or if I've just been staring at the code so long that I'm simply missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It's a client issue if it works elsewhere. Try using an object to hold the parameters instead of an array:

```
$params = new stdClass();
$params->customer = 'XBLK';
$params->size = 'four';
$params->price = 'twenty';
$results2 = $client2->boxInfo($params);
```

Comment: Using that method, I get the error "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in"

Comment: What line is that on - the call to `boxInfo()`? I'm slightly confused; you weren't passing a string originally and didn't get that error :/

Comment: Yes, it's on `the$results2 = $client2->boxInfo($params);`  line with only the `$client2 = new SoapClient...` call and php open above it.

Comment: Can you post/provide a link to the WSDL?